# All fullpage.js sections display at the same time on first load

Tags: css, fullpage.js

To get straight to the point my issue is all sections briefly displaying at the same time stacked together upon initial loading.

I found the [exact same issue asked by someone else on github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3052) and tried setting the height of all sections to 100% in css like so: `.fp-section {height: 100%!important;}` but it didn't work. (Correct me if I did it wrong.)

Then I finally found a solution that worked which was by [hiding the `body` until the fullpage.js is fully loaded](https://slicejack.com/fullpage-js-slide-fade-effect/#comment-2722990992) like so:

```
body {display:none}
body[class*="fp-viewing-"] {display:block}
```

Everything works fine with this solution EXCEPT for the responsive div that's supposed to show at certain screen width.

To clarify, my html structure consists of `<div id="fullpage">` and `<div id="responsive">` under `body`, fullpage div showing by default and responsive div set as `display: none` under media query and only showing at certain screen width.

What else can I do to stop all sections displaying the same time on first load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue with the sections, check my answer [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3425).

Basically:

Assuming `#fullpage` is your fullpage wrapper and that you use the default selectors for sections and slides:

```
html,
body,
#fullpage,
.section,
.slide,
.fp-tableCell,
{
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution didn't work for me. What is wrong with it?

Comment: perhaps you are not using the `slide` and `section` selectors for your slides and sections. Perhaps you are using wrappers around fullpage.js that are not height 100%. Possibilities are endless. Provide an isolated reproduciton in jsfiddle or codpen and we'll be able help you better.

Comment: I think I have found the issue. It is because that I am using Nuxt.js, and nuxt generates additional wrapper like `#__nuxt`, `#__layout` , `#app`. I have put `height: 100%` to all of them and it worked. For the `#app` particularly, I needed to do inline css, cause somehow it is not detecting it.

Thanks!